# Can one saved character meet another saved character in the same town?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

I wanted to know if my character, the mayor, can meet another character that I made? I can see the house that was made and freely go inside, but can my character actually meet the other?

Answer (score 1):

No. You can not have more than one player from your town active at a time.

Comment: If you want to trade items, bury them, play the other character and dig them up. Not sure if dropping them works.

Comment: Dropping them works fine.

Answer (score 1):

No, but you can visit other players visiting in your town. If you want to trade items between player residents, drop the items on the ground or attach them to a letter and send it to them.